# Variable has 'None' for gradient

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am currently using TensorFlow version 1.14.

In the code below, I am trying to create a dummy model that takes in 2 inputs and provides two outputs, with all weights set to ones and biases to zeros (Single layered perceptron). I am defining a custom loss function that computes the jacobian of the input layer wrt the output layer.

```
def my_loss(y_pred, y_true):
    jacobian_tf = jacobian_tensorflow3(sim.output, sim.input)
    loss = tf.abs(tf.linalg.det(jacobian_tf))
    return K.mean(loss)

def jacobian_tensorflow3(x,y, verbose=False):    
    jacobian_matrix = []
    it = tqdm(range(ndim)) if verbose else range(ndim)
    for o in it:
        grad_func = tf.gradients(x[:,o], y)
        jacobian_matrix.append(grad_func[0])
    jacobian_matrix = tf.stack(jacobian_matrix)
    jacobian_matrix1 = tf.transpose(jacobian_matrix, perm=[1,0,2])
    return jacobian_matrix1

sim = Sequential()
sim.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros', activation='linear', input_dim=2))
sim.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_loss)

sim.fit(B, np.random.random(B.shape), batch_size=100, epochs=2)
```

While this model works in giving the result of the Jacobian matrix and also has no issues with compilation, but when I run sim.fit I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Variable <tf.Variable 'dense_14/bias:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32> has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

I am stuck at this step for a long time, and I am not able to proceed ahead. Any help/suggestions would be beneficial.